# Can't establish Tcp StreamSocket connection between WiFiDirectServices

Tags: windows, uwp, wifi-direct

I am running the [Wi-Fi Direct services sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/wifidirectservices/) on my two Win11 laptops.

Using the default ConfigMethod, the WiFiDirectServiceSession can be created. At the step of creating socket connection, I was able to create UDP DatagramSocket and send data. But I could not create the TCP StreamSocket connection.

Here is the flow after WiFiDirectServiceSession is created.

**On computer A:**

1. StreamSocketListener is created
2. BindEndpointAsync() with a specific port number (or BindServiceNameAsync() with empty string) is called, and it is successful
3. [WiFiDirectServiceSession.AddStreamSocketListenerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect.services.wifidirectservicesession.addstreamsocketlistenerasync?view=winrt-22621) is called

**On computer B**:

4. WiFiDirectServiceSession's [RemotePortAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect.services.wifidirectservicesession.remoteportadded?view=winrt-22621) event is triggered. In RemotePortAdded handler,
5. New StreamSocket is created
6. Call StreamSocket's ConnectAsync method with either "EndpointPair" or just the "remoteHostName & remoteServiceName".  This method returns error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

The sample UWP is already listed as an allowed App in Firewall settings. I have also tried to turn off Firewalls, and the tips from this [blog](https://appuals.com/fix-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions/). But I still can't get rid of this error.

Has anyone been able to establish the Tcp connection between WiFiDirectServices?

Comment: I'm not sure but the most possible reason for this should be that the socket has been held by some process. Have you tried to reset the socket by restarting the app or restarting computer A and then test again?

Comment: I don't think that is the case.  The StreamSocketListener is created successfully (with a specific port or system selected port on Computer A) e.g. 'port123'. The error occurs when the remote computer B tries to connect to Computer A's port123.